# Booting Paravirtualized Kernel On Bare Hardware

Tags: boot, kernel, dmesg

I have been reading `dmesg` and I found the line " Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware " but I am not using Ubuntu in virtualization I am using it on my laptop **DELL N5110** the only OS I have on this machine.

> Why is it "Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware" and  what does it mean by that ?

```
[    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
```

[Full dmesg Logs](http://pastebin.com/DQrxRHHP)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have a kernel that supports running on a "[virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine)", but you are running on a real machine (bare hardware). It's harmless.